# Can I use some other + single noun

Tags: countable-nouns

I wrote a sentence *I got a maximum grade from Mathematics, Physics, Biology, and some other subject I don’t remember.*, but Grammarly thinks it's an agreement mistake and suggests changing to *some other subjects I don't remember*. It doesn't complain as well after I change it to *another subject*.

Is Grammarly right? Is some other + single noun incorrect?

Comment: Nope, you were corrected without reason. Grammarly has a stiff style that you generally won't go wrong with. If you like textbook correctness. In your case, what are you supposed to say, some other *subjects* when there was only one? I wouldn't say a "grade **from** Mathematics," but "grade in Math..."

Comment: @YosefBaskin there was only one, thanks for from->in correction, Grammarly missed that one in my case ️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammarly got it wrong.  There is no error here.  But "some" is more likely to be paired with a plural.  So a simple fix that would keep the software  (and your teachers) happy would be "... and one other subject ...".

The other correction that Grammarly makes is good.  It corrects "from" to "in".